# Angular select element looses default value when using [ngValue]

Tags: angular

I have select components that gets dynamically loaded with a reactive form

The select default value worked 100% like this:

```
<div class="selectComponent" [formGroup]="group">
    <label>{{ config.label }}</label>
    <select [formControlName]="config.name">
        <option value="">{{ config.placeholder }}</option>
        <option *ngFor="let option of config.options">
            {{ option.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

But later I realized that even though I want `option.name` to display in the dropdown list, I want a different value than the name like `option.id`

So I changed my code to:

```
<div class="selectComponent" [formGroup]="group">
    <label>{{ config.label }}</label>
    <select [formControlName]="config.name">
        <option value="">{{ config.placeholder }}</option>
        <option *ngFor="let option of config.options" [ngValue]="option.optionid">
            {{ option.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

but now the default value is gone, and the box is just empty, even though the option value `config.placeholder` is the first value in the drop-down list

Nothing I have tried have worked so far.

Comment: have you tried [value] instead? fwik [ngValue] is only used to bind objects.

Comment: @MarkusDresch I have tried `value` which gives the same effect, and now also tried `[value]` as you suggested, both give the same effect as `[ngValue]` where the box is empty and the default is the top value after clicking the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the formControl with an empty string and then everything should work as expected. The issue is that the `formControl` has a value of `null` but the placeholder option has a value of empty string

```js
group = new FormGroup({
 configuredControlName: new FormControl(""),
});
```

Alternatively, You could bind the value of the placeholder with a value of null and it would also work as expected.

```html
<option [value]="null">{{ config.placeholder }}</option>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5n9ptz)

Comment: Ahhh I see what you did there... So basically the formControl looks for an option value that is the same as the formControl value, to use as the default value, and if it doesn't find anything, it uses an empty value... (So you set formControl value = default value or default value = formControl value)