# Angular select element looses the initial value after 1sec

Tags: angular, typescript, select, angular-reactive-forms

I noticed that my select box losses initial value after 1sec.

This doesn't help -> [Angular select element looses default value when using [ngValue]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092983/angular-select-element-looses-default-value-when-using-ngvalue)

html

```js
this.profileForm = new UntypedFormGroup({
            ...
            countryCode: new UntypedFormControl(this.user.countryCode,
                Validators.compose([Validators.required])
            ),
            ...

        });
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="profile-country">Country Code*</label>
    <select formControlName="countryCode" id="profile-country" required>
        <option [value]="null">---</option>
        <option *ngFor="let country of Countries" [value]="country.countryCode">
            {{ country.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

So I see the initial value for 1 sec (Germany) and then the value is null again

Comment: I feel that, in any way, your variable "Countries" change after you create the form and when change has not the value in the array (check if you has use the same name of the variable in anyplace). See an e.g. in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ci2wwx?file=src%2Fmain.ts). After two seconds you see "Germany", when click the button, after again two seconds you can see nothing -but the value of the form still is-

Comment: you've put me on the right track, but it not the case. 
I noticed that I initialize the the country list, then the form and then country list again from observable. Country list is the same during the first and second "update" but because if the second update - select looses the initial value. 
I fixed the issue adding this:
`this.state.countryListUpdated$.subscribe(countryList => {
                **if (!this.countries?.length)** this.countriesUpdated(countryList)
            });`

Comment: **if (!this.countries?.length)** 
this is what I added, so I do not update the list if there it is not null. The list is always the same

Comment: another fix was to replace [value] with [ngValue] - what was strange to me because value is always a string

Comment: One option can be, in subscribe, before call to countriesUpdated, store in a temporaly variable the object (you need make a copy of the object, you can use some like:`const actualCountry={...this countries.find(x=>x.countryCode==form.value.countryCode)}` -see the spread operator to make a "copy" of the object and add after add it if not exist.